# How to take control of formatting a programm's output?

Tags: c, output, string-formatting

I'm running the below code for a program that takes data from 3 different .txt files. When I try to post the values by column I cannot seem to have any control on the rows which my data gets posted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int
main (void)
{
FILE *data_File;
FILE *lake_File;
FILE *beach_File;

char fileName[10], lake_Table[15],beach_Table[15];  /*.txt file names */
int lake_data=0,lake_x=0, beach_x=0, nr_tests=0;    /* variables for the data within the file july08.txt */

int province_data=0,prv_x=0;        /* variables for the file Lake Table.txt */

int beach_data=0,bch_x=0;           /* variables for the file Beach Table.txt*/

char province[30] = ""; /*variable for the file Lake Table.txt*/
char beach[20]="";   /*variable for the file Beach Table.txt*/

int j;
double status, ecoli_lvl;

printf ("Which month would you like a summary of? \nType month followed by date (i.e: july05): ");
gets(fileName);

/*Opening the files needed for the program*/
data_File = fopen (fileName, "r");
lake_File = fopen ("Lake Table.txt", "r");
beach_File = fopen ("Beach Table.txt", "r");

/*These are my columns*/
printf ("\n  Lake           Beach          Average E-Coli Level     Recommendation\n");


/* july08.txt file*/
fscanf (data_File, "%d", &lake_x);
fscanf (data_File, "%d", &beach_x);
lake_data = fscanf (data_File, "%d", &nr_tests);

/* Lake Table.txt file*/
province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
fgets (province,30,lake_File);

/* Beach Table.txt file*/
beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
fgets (beach,20,beach_File);

status = (double) 0;

while (province_data > 0)
{
    if (lake_x == prv_x)
    {
        province_data = 0;

        while (beach_data > 0)
        {
            if (beach_x == bch_x)
            {
                beach_data = 0;
            }    
            else
            {
                beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
                fgets (beach,30,beach_File);
            }
        }    
    }    
    else
    {
        province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
        fgets (province,30,lake_File);
    }
```

This is where my problem happens. I want the below two variables to be printed on the same row under their respective columns. I've edited the spaces I need but for some reason the second variable 'beach' gets posted on the second row. NOTE: The data that passes the conditional statement for the 'beach' variable is on the second row from the second file. Is that the reason why it's being posted on the second row? How do I take control of which row my data gets posted?

```
printf ("%s     %s", province, beach);

}
```

TO UPDATE THE CONDITIONAL WHILE STATEMENT (Using the strlen method)

```
while (lake_data != EOF)
{

        while (province_data > 0)
    {
        if (lake_x == prv_x)
        {

            province_data = 0;

            while (beach_data > 0)
            {
                if (beach_x == bch_x)
                {                    
                    beach_data = 0;
                }    
                else
                {
                    beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
                    fgets (beach,30,beach_File);
                }
            }    

        }    
        else
        {
            province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
            fgets (province,30,lake_File);
        }
        if (province[strlen(province)-1] =='\n')
        {
            province[strlen(province)-1] ='\0';
            beach[strlen(beach)-1] ='\0';
        }        


        /*code was right here*/


    }            

    for (j=1; j<=nr_tests; ++j)
    {
        fscanf (data_File, "%lf", &ecoli_lvl);
        status = status + ecoli_lvl;
    }


    printf ("%s      %s       %.2f", province, beach, status);    

    /* printf ("             %.2f", status); */

    /* Lake Table.txt file*/
    province_data = fscanf (lake_File, "%d", &prv_x);
    fgets (province,30,lake_File);

    /* Beach Table.txt file*/
    beach_data = fscanf (beach_File, "%d", &bch_x);
    fgets (beach,20,beach_File);

    fscanf (data_File, "\n%d", &lake_x);
    fscanf (data_File, "%d", &beach_x);
    lake_data = fscanf (data_File, "\n%d", &nr_tests);
    printf ("\n");
    status = (double) 0;
}


fclose (data_File);

return (0);
```

}
THIS IS MY OUTPUT: I'm using the tab command inside the "" to try to align my text but as you can see its not very efficient. How Can i fix this?
[image]

Comment: i would say your strings province and beach have a newline on the end?

Comment: @chris so how can I get rid of the newline when my variable picks up the strings?

Comment: fscanf doesn't keep the newline, so you can use that as opposed to fgets. alternatively like the answer below suggest, just replace the last character with a null terminator if its a newline

Comment: several I/O functions need to always have the returned value checked to assure the input/conversion operation is successful.  This includes fopen, fscanf, fgets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the input from the `fgets`, It get the line including the newline,
after that it place the null value.

While you are printing the `province` newline character placed in that string. So the second variable printed in the next line.

```
 if ( province[strlen(province)-1] == '\n' )
        province[strlen(province)-1] = '\0';
```

Testing because it can have  `EOF` character at reading last line of the file.

From man page of `fgets`,

> Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the
>          buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) for `strlen()`. It is a simple function which is used to get the total characters placed in that given string including the null character. It will work only for character string.

Like this you have to use.

```
if (province[strlen(province)-1] == '\n')
 {
    province[strlen(province)-1] = '\0';
    beach[strlen(beach)-1] = '\0';
 }

 printf ("%s     %s", province, beach);
}
```

Format:

While printing the `scanf` you can use the `-`. For printing the correct space.

```
  printf("test:%-10s\n","Testing");
```

It will give the trailing space. In this case testing is seven character so three trailing spaces will be there.

Comment: so would the same happen if i used the fscanf syntax? This is beginner's programming in C language and we haven't learned the strlen syntax yet. Is there another approach you can think of?

Comment: No you if you are using the `fscanf ` it will not act like that. I think You can read about the `strlen()` function.

Comment: I tried the strlen method but it's telling me that i'm comparing between pointer and integer...I've already assgined the type char to the variable province.

Comment: Can you post what you did?

Comment: i posted in the main body above.

Comment: You have to use the single quotes not the double quotes. Then while assigning use the single '='.

Comment: one last request. Can you see above and help me out with how to indent the text properly so that's its stationary for all the rows? thanks